# OPENROWSET fails with "Invalid authorization specification"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, openrowset, sqloledb

I am trying to use `OPENROWSET` in SQL Server 2008 SP1:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
      'SQLOLEDB', 
      'Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;',
      'select * from users')
```

- **OLE DB Provider**: `SQLOLEDB`
- **Connection String**: `Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;`
- **Command Text**: `select * from users`

The query fails with:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid authorization specification".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. Authentication failed.
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)".

**Note**: The server and credentials are, of course, correct.

### But i'm not using SQLNCLI10

The perplexing thing is the error suggests someone is using the OLE DB Provider **SQLNCLI11** *(SQL Server Native Client 11.0)*

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message

That's not the OLEDB provider i'm using.

- i'm not using OLE DB Provider: `SQLNCLI10` *(SQL Server Native Client 11.0)*
- i'm using OLE DB provider: `SQLOLEDB` *(Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server)*

So something is very wrong.

### Random tryings

Of course we can try random things:

- specify the provider in the connection string

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET(
        'SQLOLEDB', 
        'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;',
        'select * from users')
  ```
- try using the `SQLNCLI10` OLE DB provider:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET(
        'SQLNCLI10', 
        'Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;',
        'select * from users')
  ```
- try using the `SQLNCLI10` OLE DB provider:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET(
        'SQLNCLI10', 
        'Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;',
        'select * from users')
  ```
- try using **Integrated Security**

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET(
        'SQLOLEDB', 
        'Data Source=hydrogen;Integrated Security=SSPI;',
        'select * from users')
  ```

In addition to not working, these attempts don't answer my question:

> Why is the authentication failing?

### More debugging

**Use an invalid provider** - to prove that it is ignoring my provider.

The server seems insistent that i use the *"native client"*. What happens if i request an invalid OLE DB Provder - for example `asdfasf`:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
      'qqqqqq', 
      'Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;',
      'select * from users')

Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "qqqqqq" has not been registered.
```

Well that makes sense. So it's only *sometimes* ignoring my provider.

**Use a valid non-SQL Server provider**:

What if i use a valid provider that **isn't** SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
      'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
      'Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=scratch;Password=scratch;',
      'select * from users')

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

That makes sense; Office isn't installed.

### Connection string properties for provider **`SQLNCLI11`**

Property Set `DBPROPSET_DBINIT`

```
| PropertyID | Description             | Type
|------------|-------------------------|---------|
|          7 | Integrated Security     | VT_BSTR |
|          9 | Password                | VT_BSTR |
|         11 | Persist Security Info   | VT_BOOL | 
|         12 | User ID                 | VT_BSTR |
|         59 | Data Source             | VT_BSTR |
|         60 | Window Handle           | VT_I4   |
|         64 | Prompt                  | VT_I2   |
|         66 | Connect Timeout         | VT_I4   |
|        186 | Locale Identifier       | VT_I4   |
|        160 | Extended Properties     | VT_BSTR |
|        200 | Asynchronous Processing | VT_I4   |
|        233 | Initial Catalog         | VT_BSTR |
|        248 | OLE DB Services         | VT_I4   |
|        284 | General Timeout         | VT_I4   |
```

Property Set `DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT`

```
| PropertyID | Description                             | Type    |
|------------|-----------------------------------------|---------|
|          4 | Current Language                        | VT_BSTR |
|          5 | Network Address                         | VT_BSTR |
|          6 | Network Library                         | VT_BSTR |
|          7 | Use Procedure for Prepare               | VT_I4   |
|          8 | Auto Translate                          | VT_BOOL |
|          9 | Packet Size                             | VT_I4   |
|         10 | Application Name                        | VT_BSTR |
|         11 | Workstation ID                          | VT_BSTR |
|         12 | Initial File Name                       | VT_BSTR |
|         13 | Use Encryption for Data                 | VT_BOOL |
|         14 | Replication server name connect option  | VT_BSTR |
|         15 | Tag with column collation when possible | VT_BOOL |
|         16 | MARS Connection                         | VT_BOOL |
|         18 | Failover Partner                        | VT_BSTR |
|         19 | Old Password                            | VT_BSTR |
|         20 | DataTypeCompatibility                   | VT_UI2  |
|         21 | Trust Server Certificate                | VT_BOOL |
|         22 | Server SPN                              | VT_BSTR |
|         23 | Failover Partner SPN                    | VT_BSTR |
|         24 | Application Intent                      | VT_BSTR |
```

### Comparison of OLE DB Properties supported by SQLOLEDB and SQLNCLI11

**Property Set:** `DBPROPSET_DBINIT`

```
| PropertyID | Description             | Type    |  SQLOLEDB |  SQLNCLI11 |
|------------|-------------------------|---------|-----------|------------|
| 7          | Integrated Security     | VT_BSTR |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 9          | Password                | VT_BSTR |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 11         | Persist Security Info   | VT_BOOL |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 12         | User ID                 | VT_BSTR |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 59         | Data Source             | VT_BSTR |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 60         | Window Handle           | VT_I4   |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 64         | Prompt                  | VT_I2   |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 66         | Connect Timeout         | VT_I4   |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 160        | Extended Properties     | VT_BSTR |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 186        | Locale Identifier       | VT_I4   |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 200        | Asynchronous Processing | VT_I4   |           |  Yes       |
| 233        | Initial Catalog         | VT_BSTR |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 248        | OLE DB Services         | VT_I4   |  Yes      |  Yes       |
| 284        | General Timeout         | VT_I4   |  Yes      |  Yes       |
```

**Property Set:** `DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT`

```
| PropertyID | Description                             | Type    |  SQLOLEDB | SQLNCLI11 |
|------------|-----------------------------------------|---------|-----------|-----------|
| 4          | Current Language                        | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 5          | Network Address                         | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 6          | Network Library                         | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 7          | Use Procedure for Prepare               | VT_I4   |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 8          | Auto Translate                          | VT_BOOL |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 9          | Packet Size                             | VT_I4   |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 10         | Application Name                        | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 11         | Workstation ID                          | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 12         | Initial File Name                       | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 13         | Use Encryption for Data                 | VT_BOOL |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 14         | Replication server name connect option  | VT_BSTR |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 15         | Tag with column collation when possible | VT_BOOL |  Yes      | Yes       |
| 16         | MARS Connection                         | VT_BOOL |           | Yes       |
| 18         | Failover Partner                        | VT_BSTR |           | Yes       |
| 19         | Old Password                            | VT_BSTR |           | Yes       |
| 20         | DataTypeCompatibility                   | VT_UI2  |           | Yes       |
| 21         | Trust Server Certificate                | VT_BOOL |           | Yes       |
| 22         | Server SPN                              | VT_BSTR |           | Yes       |
| 23         | Failover Partner SPN                    | VT_BSTR |           | Yes       |
| 24         | Application Intent                      | VT_BSTR |           | Yes       |
```

Comment: I'm not terribly surprised SQL Server internally redirects `sqloledb` to `sqlncli`; the former is old, and really intended for legacy clients like ADO. You could simply *not* fight the future and use `OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=hydrogen;UID=scratch;PWD=scratch', ..)`. The list of valid keywords is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client). If you have a pressing reason to use exactly that connection string, it'll be a little harder.

Comment: Here's a fun factoid: `OPENDATASOURCE` still supports `sqloledb`, old keywords and all. No, I don't know where that discrepancy is coming from.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You'll notice that i tried that. Also note that Microsoft [deprecated SQLNCLI native client](http://archive.is/eslqb), and [recommend you use SQLOLEDB instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/support-policies-for-sql-server-native-client#ole-db-support-policies)

Comment: No, you never tried using `UID` and `PWD` anywhere; you tried to use `User ID` and `Password` with `SQLNCLI`, which will not work. And yes, I am aware of that ominous 7 year old deprecation notice (OLE DB is dead, use ODBC!), but that has itself been [superseded](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/). The new driver (`msoledbsql`) should not be relevant to your case since you're still on SQL Server 2008, which is out of support anyway.

Answer (score 9):

If you clear spaces in the connection string it should work,

```
SELECT a.*  
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SQLOLEDB;Database=hydrogen;UID=scratch;PWD=scratch',  
     'SELECT * 
      FROM Users') AS a;
```